# Excel option button in multiple groups work as single group

Tags: vba, excel

I have created one questionnaire in Excel using VBA which loads question and options on runtime. This strange issue happens whenever I change something like fonts / formatting / or (don't know exactly what all).

I create radio buttons with code:

```
With btn1
        .Name = QuestionNum & "_" & FoundCell.Offset(0, 2).Address & "_" & NestedQuestions & "_" & FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Address
        .Caption = Space(5) & FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Text
        .OnAction = "ChangeAnswer"
        .Display3DShading = True
        .Width = 290
End With
  Set grbox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).GroupBoxes.Add(t.Left + 20, t.Top, t.Width + 10, t.Height)
  With grbox
        .Caption = QuestionNum
        .Text = QuestionNum & "GB"
        .Visible = False
    End With
```

And add them all to group box. This approach worked for quite sometime and then stops working. In current situation, it's taking all options as single group instead of small individual groups for each questions.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question/problem? I don't understand what is happening, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: There are multiple questions. E.g. Q1 has 3 options, so user can choose any one of the option. Same goes on and on. Issue is that all the options are working as one so user can choose any one option from the entire sheet, and not specific to the question. If you see the code for adding group, I am adding group after creating radio button for each question in loop.